# Synonyms for small in stature

Tags: word-choice, synonyms

With "big in stature", we have large, tall, rotund, huge, mammoth-like, towering and so on. What would be valid (and if possible, comical sounding) words that would be able to describe somebody who is small in stature, short, petite?

Comment: ‘Short’ and ‘petite’ are both quite good synonyms themselves … Have you tried looking these up in a thesaurus? And can you tell us why you were not satisfied with what you found there?

Comment: Short, Petite, Miniature, Microscopic, Tiny. None of them really say "you are a very small person"

Comment: how about 'diminutive'?

Comment: Perhaps *wee* ?

Comment: I feel like `wee` is too localized, which is why I didn't include it in my answer.  Every time I hear it, I imagine a Scottish or Irish speaker, regardless of whether that's correct or not (yay media influences).

Answer (score 1):

If you're going for more comical, there's the classic "shrimp".

Alternatives:  "pint-sized", "vertically challenged", "teeny", "knee-high to a grasshopper"; "Stubby", "elfin", "minuscule", "miniature", "mini".

I'd suggest try to avoid dwarf and midget due to recent political correctness trends, though they are valid possibilities (and used to be quite common, especially midge).

**Note:** All of these were found via Google's thesaurus function: [Google Power!](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=short+synonym) (Clicking on 'More' under the "(of a person) small in height" entry shows the informal entries most likely to be what you're looking for)